# Movieclip attraction/repulsion to mouse

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm really new to flash and as3...
I'm trying to create 2 scenes in flash - one where my movieclip moves away from the mouse whenever it goes near it, and the other where the movie clip is attracted to the mouse. I have found an answer on actionscript 2 but i cannot use this in my as3 file...
Any help or ideas?
Cheers!

Comment: Your question is quite localized. I'm sure you can find plenty of exaxmples out there. If you're not familiar with as3 but want to get some utilities I recommend having a look at [Hype](http://www.hypeframework.org/). Back to your question try [this](http://www.hypeframework.org/01_background/content/mousefollow-as3/), all you need is a direction variable which you multiply after  the ease and it's value is 1 for attraction or -1 for repulsion.

Comment: Yeah i am really new to flash... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I made of a display object being "pushed" and "pulled" in relation to the mouse's position.

**Main.as(Document class):**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Main extends Sprite  
    {

        public static var PULL:String = "pull";
        public static var PUSH:String = "push";

        private var _circle:Circle;
        private var _force:String;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _circle = new Circle();
            addChild(_circle);

            _force = PULL;

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStageMouseDown);

        }// end function

        private function onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame);

        }// end function

        private function onStageMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame);

            _force = (_force == PULL) ? PUSH : PULL;

        }// end function

        private function onStageEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
        {
            var point1:Point = new Point(_circle.x, _circle.y);
            var point2:Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
            var point3:Point = point2.subtract(point1);
            point3.normalize(10);

            if (_force == PULL) {

                _circle.x += point3.x;
                _circle.y += point3.y;

            } else if (_force == PUSH) {

                _circle.x -= point3.x;
                _circle.y -= point3.y;

            }// end else if

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

class Circle extends Sprite {

    public function Circle() {

        draw();

    }// end function

    private function draw():void {

        this.graphics.lineStyle(1);
        this.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        this.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 20);
        this.graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

}// end class
```

In the `init()` method we add a new display object to the stage, this is the display object we will be "pulling" and "pushing" in relation to the mouse's position.

```
_circle = new Circle();
addChild(_circle);
```

Then we set the `_force` property to our `PULL` constant. The `_force` property will determine whether the display object is "pulled" or "pushed".

```
_force = PULL;
```

Next we add our mouse event listeners to the stage. On `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` we call the `onStageMouseDown()` event handler. When the handler is called, we add an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event listeners to the stage.

```
private function onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame);

}// end function
```

When the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event handler is called, the previous `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event listeners are removed from the stage. Then depending on the `_force` property's value, its value is alternated between `PUSH` and `PULL`.

```
private function onStageMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame);

    _force = (_force == PULL) ? PUSH : PULL;

}// end function
```

Lastly, the `onStageEnterFrame` event handler. This is where we calculate the new position of the display object in relation to the mouse.

There are different ways to go about this, but I decided to use the `Point` class to simplify things. First we have to get a `Point` object for the display object's position and another `Point` object for mouse's position.

```
var point1:Point = new Point(_circle.x, _circle.y);
var point2:Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
```

Next we have to get the difference between the points using the `Point` object's `subtract()` method.

```
var point3:Point = point2.subtract(point1);
```

With this new point, we can use the `Point` object's `normalize()` method to scale the line segment between the display object's position and the mouse's position to a set length.

```
point3.normalize(10);
```

Finally depending on the _force property's value we either subtract or add the point's `x` and `y` properties from the display object's `x` and `y` properties.

Comment: Wow, i literally got all of that. thanks so much for explaining it... :)